# Windows user allow write file with specific name

Tags: windows, security, ftp, file-permissions

Is it possible to allow specific user in Windows for specific folder:

1. read any file
2. delete any file
3. write (create) files only with specific name like ABC*.TXT (for example ABC123456.TXT)

This user connects to FTP on Windows Server 2012. User has access to specific folder and I want to deny him to write files except ABC*.TXT (other TXT files should be denied). I can't find any kind of solution in folder properties. Is it possible to do so? Or do I need some additional software?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, but there exist other standard methods for separating the files
of users using Windows authentication.

The usual method is to create a sub-folder per user where he may create files
and have full permissions. If you don't want him to see other folders,
then set this folder in FTP as his root folder.

If the user needs to see all the files, set his root folder as the parent folder,
and give him full permissions only on his folder.

However, it's not possible in Windows to give a user the right to delete files
in a folder without also giving him the full modify permission on the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your third requirement can not be met by simple DACLs. If you have a set of files he should be able to modify, that can be done. You just grant him the modify permissions for those files. It seems strange that he would be able to delete any file, include the other txt files. Check your FTP server software as well as some of them offer additional options for permissions management. For instance maybe he can only read and write files that were created by him.